# Image not moving in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```py
# import pygame module in this program 
import pygame 
  
# activate the pygame library . 
# initiate pygame and give permission 
# to use pygame's functionality. 
pygame.init() 
  
# define the RGB value 
# for white colour 
white = (255, 255, 255) 
  
# assigning values to X and Y variable 
X = 800
Y = 500
xa=0
ya=0  
# create the display surface object 
# of specific dimension..e(X, Y). 
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y )) 
  
# set the pygame window name 
pygame.display.set_caption('Image') 
  
# create a surface object, image is drawn on it. 
image = pygame.image.load(r'ball.png') 
  
# infinite loop 
while True : 
    xa+=1
    ya+=1
    # completely fill the surface object 
    # with white colour 
    display_surface.fill(white) 
  
    # moving the image surface object 
    # to the display surface object at 
    display_surface.blit(image, (xa, ya))
    # iterate over the list of Event objects 
    # that was returned by pygame.event.get() method. 
    for event in pygame.event.get() : 
  
        # if event object type is QUIT 
        # then quitting the pygame 
        # and program both. 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT : 
  
            # deactivates the pygame library 
            pygame.quit() 
  
            # quit the program. 
            quit() 
        # Draws the surface object to the screen.   
        pygame.display.update()
```

I am trying to make an image move in a particular direction as I am a beginner. But the image is not moving. I am new to python so It's hard for me to figure out what's the mistake so Please tell me what's the problem.

Comment: pygame.display.update() should be outside of event for loop

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to update the display in the application loop rather the event loop:

```py
# infinite loop 
while True : 
    xa+=1
    ya+=1
    # completely fill the surface object 
    # with white colour 
    display_surface.fill(white) 

    # moving the image surface object 
    # to the display surface object at 
    display_surface.blit(image, (xa, ya))
    # iterate over the list of Event objects 
    # that was returned by pygame.event.get() method. 
    for event in pygame.event.get() : 

        # if event object type is QUIT 
        # then quitting the pygame 
        # and program both. 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT : 

            # deactivates the pygame library 
            pygame.quit() 

            # quit the program. 
            quit() 

    #<--| INDENTATION

    # Draws the surface object to the screen.   
    pygame.display.update()
```

Note, the application loop is executed in each frame, but the event loop is only entered when an event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Put the display.update() outside of for loop but inside while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You put the update function in the wrong loop, try this code, it should work.

```py
# import pygame module in this program 
import pygame 

# activate the pygame library . 
# initiate pygame and give permission 
# to use pygame's functionality. 
pygame.init() 

# define the RGB value 
# for white colour 
white = (255, 255, 255) 

# assigning values to X and Y variable 
X = 800
Y = 500
xa=0
ya=0  
# create the display surface object 
# of specific dimension..e(X, Y). 
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y )) 

# set the pygame window name 
pygame.display.set_caption('Image') 

# create a surface object, image is drawn on it. 
image = pygame.image.load(r'ball.png') 

# infinite loop 
while True : 
    xa+=1
    ya+=1
    # completely fill the surface object 
    # with white colour 
    display_surface.fill(white) 

    # moving the image surface object 
    # to the display surface object at 
    display_surface.blit(image, (xa, ya))
    # iterate over the list of Event objects 
    # that was returned by pygame.event.get() method. 
    for event in pygame.event.get() : 

        # if event object type is QUIT 
        # then quitting the pygame 
        # and program both. 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT : 

            # deactivates the pygame library 
            pygame.quit() 

            # quit the program. 
            quit() 
        # Draws the surface object to the screen.   
    pygame.display.update()
```